# How to handle Task Exceptions in GUI?

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception, task-parallel-library

What is the recommended way to handle errors when using Tasks to unblock the UI and using Aync/Await is not an option?

I typically want to handle expected errors by updating the UI and handle unexpected Errors (log Exception(s), inform user and shutdown app) in a global error handler like Application_DispatcherUnhandledException.

I am playing with the following approach which looks ugly to me.

```
Private Sub _showAsyncButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles _showAsyncButton.Click
Dim task = New WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://www.microsoft.com")
'Dim task = New WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync("forcing error in async I/O")
task.ContinueWith(
    Sub()
        _resultField.Text = task.Result
        'Throw New ApplicationException("forcing error in End method")
    End Sub, Nothing, Nothing, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext
    ).ContinueWith(
        Sub(a)
            Select Case True
                Case TypeOf (a.Exception.GetBaseException) Is WebException AndAlso CType(a.Exception.GetBaseException, WebException).Status = WebExceptionStatus.NameResolutionFailure
                    'Handle expected error
                    Dispatcher.Invoke(Sub() MessageBox.Show("Cannot access web site. Please try again later"))
                Case Else
                    'Rethrow unexpected error in global error handler
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub() ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(a.Exception).Throw())
                    'ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(aex).Throw() 'Does not work 
            End Select
        End Sub, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted)
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handling exceptions in a parallel application alongside handling many other stuff is a painful task and requires sufficient knowledge and skill. Consider re-writing the above code using `async-await` keywords introduced in .Net 4.5, it then allows you to handle exceptions in the same way you did in a synchronous programming model. Of course, there exists some situations when `async-await` is not adequate and you need to directly use TPL API.

You could then use a .Net decompiler (i.e. .Net Reflector) to see how much work compiler did on behalf of you, it would also be an invaluable learning source.

Also Consider taking a look at [Exception Handling with the Task Parallel Library](http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2010/10/exception-handling-with-the-task-parallel-library/) which provides you with a good insight on how to deal with exceptions when doing parallel programming using TPL.

The "[The zen of async: Best practices for best performance](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-829T)" presented by Stephen Toub also dives deeply into how `async`works under the hoods in .Net 4.5 and it covers some advanced topics which exception handling is one of those.

Comment: I know that this error handling problem can be solved nicely with Await. But I want to have a robust error handling pattern for usage without  Await too. I updated my code example with a cleaner version with better comments.

Comment: For a deeper discussion of this question see [How to handle Task Exceptions in GUI without Await? ] (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/parallelextensions/thread/7e71f7e1-6c89-4129-bd74-bc6adb1242d1). For an alternative solution see [Exception-handling wrappers for Task.ContinueWith()] (http://www.rizalalmashoor.com/blog/exception-handling-wrappers-for-taskcontinuewith/)